# Google authentication with email and password.

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-developer-api, google-authenticator, android-authenticator

I am creating an application that uses google drive api,  and requires authentication of a google account. The example on the quick start for using drive api for android uses google sign_in where user would be required to choose an account from the google accounts already added on the phone.

I dont want user to choose there own account. I want to add the account the api would be used in from code, such that files would be accessed from my own specified accounr not that of the user of the app. But I cant seam to find any sign_in or authentication form apart from the case when user is to choose an account.

Please can this be done? And if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Answer would be simple No, you can do that but you have to use different API than that of Google's one. Google will ask to choose from account as it is added in implicit intent.

Comment: But if I use a different api for the authentication, then I cant use googles drive api right?